# Laravel sentry set environment

Tags: laravel, sentry

I am setting up sentry for my project, i currently have 3 environments for it local, staging and production.

I am only wanting to set it so sentry tracks staging and production and we ignore local entirely but from looking at the documentation i didnt find anything to help me with this.

**Handler method**

This method was taking straight from the docs and added into my handler method

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if (app()->bound('sentry') && $this->shouldReport($exception)) {
        app('sentry')->captureException($exception);
    }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

**sentry config**

```
return [

'dsn' => env('SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN', env('SENTRY_DSN')),

// capture release as git sha
// 'release' => trim(exec('git --git-dir ' . base_path('.git') . ' log --pretty="%h" -n1 HEAD')),

'breadcrumbs' => [
    // Capture Laravel logs in breadcrumbs
    'logs' => true,

    // Capture SQL queries in breadcrumbs
    'sql_queries' => true,

    // Capture bindings on SQL queries logged in breadcrumbs
    'sql_bindings' => true,

    // Capture queue job information in breadcrumbs
    'queue_info' => true,
],
```

];

**env file**

```
SENTRY_DSN=dsdsdsds
```

does anyone have any guidance on how to set this up to to track certain environments and do i need to set any extra env keys?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `SENTRY_DSN=` in you .env locally to null or remove it, it will never get send out because the DSN is missing so nowhere to sent it to.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/laravel/#local-development

Comment: I understand this but i am wanting to track staging and production

Comment: For staging and production you should set the right dns for SENTRY_DSN= . They should all  have an individual .env file.